# How can I stop the Gmail web based chat going idle when I switch browser tabs?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

I have a Gmail tab open in the browser (Firefox 4.0) all the time with chat enabled.
However, when I move to a different tab for a while, then move back to the Gmail tab my chat status has changed to idle (orange).

Is there a way to prevent it moving to idle while when the tab is not active?

---

Update: Happens on Chrome too.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Al you can test it if you can login to another account and add you as a chat friend to see that you're actually going into idle mode when you're away from the tab :) as soon as the focus regained you're back on online (green) mode.

Comment: @Al. Firefox 4.0. I'll try something different and see if I get the same behaviour.

Comment: You can see it quickly switch back from idle to active if you're fast at tab switching @ale

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an awesome solution, but if you could use a desktop client like Trillian, you could "force" it to never show you as away. That means the gmail page wouldn't be able to change your status either.

Comment: Thanks. Yes sadly I've had to settle for a desktop client.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an awesome Extension for Chrome that solves this problem.  It provides direct access to Google Talk from the browser.  You can sign-out of Google Talk/Chat in Gmail and access everything from the browser extension.

The extension also supports making and receiving calls through Google Voice.

[Chat for Google Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd)

I'm running the current dev release (20.0.1132.11 dev-m) of Chrome and the extension works great.

Answer (score -1):

Set up automatic refresh on your webpage for every 2-5 minutes or more possibly.

Comment: And how do you do that?